# Firebase Firestore extend to Cloud Functions to put more informations by Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I tried to extend my `Firestore` to `Functions` and triggered `onCreate`at Firestore saved.

**I want to save each UIDs by Firebase Authentication (By Admin SDK).**

- This `Collection` is made automatically by webhook
- Each `Documents` include Personal Informations more than 1 people (2 in there).

But I got this Error » *"admin.auth.getUserByPhoneNumber is not a function"*

> Is anybody there to make Example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context you are trying to use it, `admin.auth` is a helper function to get the [Auth object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth) of the default application initialized by `admin.initializeApp()`.

Change your line so that the `admin.auth()` function is called.

```js
admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(/* ... */)
//        ^^
```